# Selenium issues in colab. No content as result

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, google-colaboratory

The result is the same... No content as result

I don't understand

```
wd.get("https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Olla+popular&title=Especial:Buscar&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&ns0=1&ns100=1&ns104=1&searchToken=1yxuj0001jqyu03r57ihshghs")
titulo=[]
url=[]
titulos = wd.find_elements('xpath','.//*[@class="mw-search-result-heading"]//*[@title]')
vinculos = wd.find_elements('xpath','.//*[@class="mw-search-result-heading"]//*[@href]')

for lista in wikipedia:
    titulo.append(titulos)
    url.append(vinculos)

wikipedia= {'TITULO':titulo, "URL": url}
print(wikipedia)`
```

Result:

```
{'TITULO': [[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="c80b388b81c0a92f765e12e98bf9e873", element="AAA15E81614032C0EA8A04A7CDDFDF3C_element_715")>, ...
```

And so on...

The result is the same for: `links =wd.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")`

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).